# sshfs with pexpect reported no error but failed to mount (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint, pexpect

I ask for help!

```
command = "sshfs " + username + "@" + host + ":" + hostdirectory \
        + " " + mountpoint + " -o nonempty "
 
sshfs = pexpect.spawn(command)
sshfs.expect(username + "@" + host + "'s password: ")
time.sleep(1)
sshfs.sendline(password)
time.sleep(10)
sshfs.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Runs without error, but `/home/user/Mnt/` is empty. I run the code on Linux Mint 20.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sshfs` should have been killed by `SIGHUP` prematurely.

Try ignoring `SIGHUP` like this:

```
command = "sshfs " + ...
pexpect.spawn('bash', args=['-c', "trap '' HUP; " + command])
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Same effect for ignoring `SIGHUP` signal by keyword argument `ignore_sighup=True`. It's keeping `sshfs` running in background.

```
sshfs = pexpect.spawn(command, ignore_sighup=True)
```

[See doc](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.__init__)